# Sidekiq is not processing jobs

Tags: sidekiq

I´m new to Sidekiq. I´m trying to run a basic example integrated in my webapp. So, at the moment:

1. I have redis listening.
2. I have created a worker in /my-project-root/app/workers/hard_worker.rb like this:

   ```
   require 'sidekiq'
   require 'utils_service.rb' # External service in lib folder with the process functionality


   Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
       config.redis = {db:1}
   end 

   Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
       config.redis = {db:1}
   end 


   class HardWorker
     include Sidekiq::Worker

     def perform()
       logger.debug "Initializing integration..."
       doWhatever()
     end
   end
   ```
3. From my webapp, the user can send a request to a controller to run a method that should create a job, like:

Controller:

```
def manageWorker
      logger.debug "manageWorker-->before calling HardWorker."
      HardWorker.perform_async()
      logger.debug "manageWorker-->after calling HardWorker."
end
```

3. I have my webapp up and running in a websocket (I just say this because I don´t know if it´s important or not to find the route cause of the problem).
4. I start sidekiq server with:

   cd /my-project-root

   bundle exec sidekiq -d -L log/sidekiq.log

The server sends some startup logs to the log file. However, when I send the request to the controller, I can see the function has been run. In my webapp log file I can see:

```
manageWorker-->before calling HardWorker.
manageWorker-->after calling HardWorker.
```

So, aparently the job is executed. However, nothing happens. I cannot see any log in the sidekiq log file.

What am I missing?

I just wanted to point out the paths of the files and where I start the sidekiq server, because I think could be related to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The debug level is only output with `-v`.